# text-align in md-grid-tile (Angular Material) doesn't work

Tags: angular-material, text-align

`text-align` in Angular Material `<md-grid-tile>` doesn't work.

```html
<md-grid-tile>{{video.created}}</md-grid-tile>
<md-grid-tile>{{video.code</md-grid-tile>

<md-grid-tile style="text-align: left;">
   {{ video.title }}
</md-grid-tile>

<md-grid-tile>{{video.playtime}}</md-grid-tile>
```

I want to align text like this:

[image]

but `text-align` in `<md-grid-tile>` didn't work :(

How can I do it?

Comment: Try <md-grid-tile style="text-align: left !important;">

Comment: I tried `<md-grid-tile style="text-align: left !important;">` but it also didn't work, sorry

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You could simply put a `span` or `div` tag around your text inside `md-grid-tile`:

```
<md-grid-tile>
    <div class="text-inside-grid">{{ video.title }}</div>
</md-grid-tile>
```

and then style it:

```
.text-inside-grid {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: It works perfect for <mat-grid-tile> too (angular 5 material: <mat-grid-list>)

Comment: why it is position: absolute instead of position: relative ?

Comment: I couldn't remember how `md-grid-tile` works but I think that's because you'd want to position your text relative to its parent (md-grid-tile).

Answer (score 14):

for those who have problems getting this example to work in angular2
you might need to add the **::ng-deep** selector to the css for the figure

```
<md-grid-tile class="video-title">
    {{ video.title }}
</md-grid-tile>
```

css

```
 .video-title > ::ng-deep figure {
     justify-content: flex-start !important;
 }
```

*updated /deep/ to ::ng-deep because /deep/ was deprecated

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative with flex-layout (and using the latest 'mat-' prefix):

```
<mat-grid-tile>
    <div fxFlex fxLayoutAlign="start center">{{ video.title }}</div>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it!

```
<md-grid-tile>{{video.created}}</md-grid-tile>
<md-grid-tile>{{video.code</md-grid-tile>

<md-grid-tile style="text-align: left;" class="video-title">
    {{ video.title }}
</md-grid-tile>

<md-grid-tile>{{video.playtime}}</md-grid-tile>
```

css

```
.video-title > figure {
    justify-content: flex-start !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Target `div` elements inside `mat-grid-tile` with a width of 100 percent.

my.component.scss

```
mat-grid-tile div {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

my.component.html

```
<mat-grid-list cols="12">
  <mat-grid-tile colspan="4">
    <img [src]="hero.avatarUrl" i18n-alt alt="Hero avatar" />
  </mat-grid-tile>

  <mat-grid-tile colspan="8">
    <div>
      <h1>
        {{ hero.firstName }}
        {{ hero.lastName }}
      </h1>
    </div>
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```